# Connect existing Hive tables to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, hive, kibana

What is the way to connect existing Hive tables to ES and visualize them using Kibana?

Answer (score 0):

Create external tables, which point to ElasticSearch in the storage method:

For example:

```
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE car (
>     id      BIGINT,
>     brand   STRING,
>     specs   STRUCT<url:STRING, picture:STRING>) STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'
> TBLPROPERTIES('es.resource' = 'cars');
```